# Trying to convert PHP assignment to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to convert a PHP function to javascript, but i cant read the following line of codes:

```
  $sha_string .= "$key=$value$ipn_passphrase";
```

and

```
 $sha_sign = strtoupper(hash("sha512", $sha_string));
```

Complete function:

```
function digistore_signature( $ipn_passphrase, $array)
{
    unset($array[ 'sha_sign' ]);

    $keys = array_keys($array);
    sort($keys);

    $sha_string = "";

    foreach ($keys as $key)
    {
        $value = html_entity_decode( $array[ $key ] );

        $is_empty = !isset($value) || $value === "" || $value === false;

        if ($is_empty)
        {
            continue;
        }

        $sha_string .= "$key=$value$ipn_passphrase";
    }

    $sha_sign = strtoupper(hash("sha512", $sha_string));

    return $sha_sign;
}
```

the $array is the body of a POST request.
the $passphrase is a string

Comment: Do you mean 'read' as in 'comprehend'? Let `$key` be `key`, `$value` be `123`, and `$ipn_passphrase` be `pass`. This way, `$sha_string` is `'key=123pass'` because the variables get parsed and converted into a String. Then `$sha_sign` takes that variable and encrypts it using the SHA-512 algorithm, which then is converted to uppercase characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.=` in PHP is a simple concatenation. it is similar to the programming concept of `+=`. It's easy to understand with an example

```
<?php

$a = "hello";
$a .= " ";  //now $a = "hello "
$a .= "world"; // now $a = "hello world"
```

`"$key=$value$ipn_passphrase";` is called an in-place variable substitution in PHP. You can check the [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more. You can simply consider it as the value `$key`, `$values` and `$ipn_passphrase` is replaced by the values of those variables accordingly and it forms a new string variable `$sha_sign`.

`$sha_sign = strtoupper(hash("sha512", $sha_string));` is a simple statement where you pass the algorithm `sha512` and `$sha_string` to the function `hash()` and store the result back in `$sha_string` variable.

Comment: I dont really get you on the in-place variable substitution :(
and the docs arent getting me further either...